# Convex and bounded function is constant

Tags: calculus

Let f be a convex and  bounded function, meaning there is a constant $C$, such that $f(x) < C$ for every $x$.

I need to prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose f is not constant, i.e., $\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)>f(y)$.
Since f is convex, we have: $f(x)\leq\lambda f(\frac{x-(1-\lambda)y}{\lambda})+(1-\lambda)f(y)\;\;\;\forall\lambda\in(0,1).$

(This is just the definition of convexity, $f(\lambda x'+(1-\lambda)y')\leq\lambda f(x')+(1-\lambda)f(y')\;\;\;\forall\lambda\in(0,1)$, with $x=\lambda x'+(1-\lambda)y'$ and $y=y'$.)

Hence $\frac{f(x)-(1-\lambda)f(y)}{\lambda}\leq f(\frac{x-(1-\lambda)y}{\lambda}).$

Now, since $f(x)>f(y)$, $\frac{f(x)-(1-\lambda)f(y)}{\lambda}=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{\lambda}+f(y)\rightarrow \infty$ as $\lambda\rightarrow0^+.$

Hence f is not bounded above.

Comment: The same argument holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: What can you say about derivatives of convex functions? Then compare the straight line joining two points (say $x$ and $x_1$) with the tangent line at $x$

Comment: A piecewise constant function is not convex.

Comment: a convex function is automatically Lipschitz. Its left and right derivatives automatically exist, and it is non-differentiable at at most countably many points. For the question asked, it is not necessary to make the assumption that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: @Theo, @Willie, thanks I have edited my hint