# Robust feasibility with halfspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have

$$ a_1^\top x + b_1 \leq f(x) \leq a_2^\top x + b_2 $$

for some given $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in \text{conv}( \{x^1, ..., x^N \} )$.

Say if there exists $( c,d ) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that the halfspace $$H(c,d) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid c^\top x \leq d \}$$ is such that

$$ f(x) \leq 0 \ \ \forall x \in H(c,d) \\ x^i \in H(c,d) \ \ \forall i=1,...,N $$

Comment. The statement is clearly true if $f$ is affine. I am wondering about this more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the beginning of your question and the comment. :-) It seems that the function $f$ should be affine, by the following. If $a_1\not=a_2$, then there is a vector $x=\lambda(a_1-a_2)\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $a_1^\top x+b_1>a_2^\top x+b_2$. Moreover, if $ a^\top x + b_1 \leq f(x) \leq a^\top x + b_2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is a convex, then $f$ should be affine, because $f$ is affine on each one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Indeed, let $g$ be a convex function on $\mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ we have $ax + b_1 \leq g(x) \leq ax + b_2$ for some given $a,b_1,b_2\in\mathbb R$. Then a function $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $h(x)=g(x)-ax$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ is a convex bounded function on $\mathbb R$, and, hence, [constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24397/convex-and-bounded-function-is-constant).

Comment: Why? Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f(x) = \lambda_{\max}( A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 )$ - where $\lambda_{\max}$ denotes the maximum eigenvalue - for some given square matrices $A_1, A_2$. Then $f$ is convex, both sublinear and superlinear, both not affine. Am I wrong?

Comment: It seems the following. The solution of the characteristic equation $|A_1x_1+A_2x_2-\lambda I|=0$ yields $\lambda_{max}(x)=l(x)+\sqrt{q(x)}$, where $l$ is a linear form, and $q$ is a quadratic form. The form $l$ does not change the convexity of $f$. Since $f(x)$ should be defined for each $x$, the form $q$ is non-negative. Consider, for instance, the form $q(x)=(x,x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$. The restriction of $\sqrt{q}$ on the line $x_2=0$ is equal to $|x_1|$, which is not sublinear. Is this OK?

Comment: I am totally unclear to your comment. Can you please explain it better? Thanks.

Comment: 1. $\lambda_{max}(A_1x_1+A_2x_2)$ is the largest root of the characteristic equation $|A_1x_1+A_2x_2-\lambda I|=0$.  If $A_1=\left(\begin{matrix} a_1 & b_1\\ c_1 & d_1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $A_2=\left(\begin{matrix} a_2 & b_2\\ c_2 & d_2\end{matrix}\right)$ then $|A_1x_1+A_2x_2-\lambda I|=\left|\begin{matrix} a_1x_1+a_2x_2-\lambda & b_1x_1+b_2x_2\\ c_1x_1+c_2x_2 & d_1x_1+d_2x_2-\lambda\end{matrix}\right|$ $=\lambda^2-\lambda(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+d_1x_1+d_2x_2)-(b_1x_1+b_2x_2)(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)$. Put $l(x)=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+d_1x_1+d_2x_2)/2$ and $q(x)=l(x)^2+(b_1x_1+b_2x_2)(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)$.

Comment: Then the the largest root of the characteristic equation is eqaul to $l(x)+\sqrt{q(x)}$. If $f(x)$ is (non)convex, (non) sublinear, (non) superlinear, or (not) affine, then so is $\sqrt{q(x)}$. Since $f(x)$ should be defined for each $x$, the form $q$ is non-negative.

Comment: Choosing the respective basis, we may consider that $q(x)=(x,x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ (or $q(x)=(x,x)=x_1^2$ or $q(x)=0$ in degenerate cases). If the function $\sqrt{q}$ were sublinear, the restriction of $\sqrt{q}$ on the line $x_2=0$ were be sublinear too. But this restriction is equal to $|x_1|$, which is not sublinear.

Comment: I am still not clear, sorry. So, consider $\lambda_{\max}(A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2) \leq \lambda_{\max}(A_1) x_1 + \lambda_{\max}(A_2) x_2 = [\lambda_{\max}(A_1),\lambda_{\max}(A_2)] x$ because of Jensen's inequality and to the fact that $\lambda_{\max}(A \alpha) = \alpha(A)$. This means that the $\lambda_{\max}$ mapping is sublinear, right?

Comment: Based on the inequality $$ a_1^\top x + b_1 \leq f(x) \leq a_2^\top x + b_2 $$ from your question I thought that sublinearity of the function $f$ means: (1) there is a linear function $L$ such that $f(x)\le L(x)$ for each $x$. This condition is different from a variant of Jensen’s inequality (2): $f(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)\le f(a_1)x_1+ f(a_2)x_2$, which should (imply the convexity and) hold for *non-negative* values of $x_1$ and $x_2$. For instance, the function $f(x)=|x|$ should satisfy condition (2), but not (1).

Comment: Why the $x_i$'s should be non-negative? Please see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality]. Moreover, why does $f(x) = |x|$ is a useful example?

Comment: Concerning the [finite form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#Finite_form) of Jensen's inequality, at this page is written: “For a real convex function $\varphi$, numbers $x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n$ in its domain, and *positive* weights $a_i$, Jensen's inequality can be stated as:$\dots$. In the inequality $$\lambda_{max}(A_1x_1 +A_2x_2)\le \lambda_{max}(A_1)x_1+\lambda_{max}(A_2)x_2,$$ $\lambda_{max}$ is a (convex)function, $A_i$ are elements in its domain, and $x_i$ are weights, isn’t it?

Comment: The function $|x|$ should be a useful example, because it is convex and satisfies an equality $|\alpha x|=\alpha |x|$ for a non-negative $\alpha$. Moreover, as I wrote earlier, there should exist matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that $|x|$ is a restriction of a function $f(x)=\lambda_{max}(A_1x_1+A_2x_2)$ onto a line.

Comment: No, sorry. Consider weights $a_i = 1$ and $A_i x_i$ as elements in its domain. Right?

Comment: In this case we should have $\lambda_{max}((A_1x_1+A_2x_2)\le (\lambda_{max}(A_1x_1)+ \lambda_{max} (A_2x_2))$. On the right side of the inequality we cannot take out negative $x_i$ from the brackets, because $\lambda_{max}(–A_i)=–\lambda_{min}(A_i)$, which is not necessarily equal to $–\lambda_{max}(A_i)$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your explanation.