# Show bounded and convex function on ℝ is constant (pt 2)

Tags: calculus

Continuing from: [Show bounded and convex function on $\mathbb R$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518091/show-bounded-and-convex-function-on-is-constant)

My thoughts: Assume a line through $(a, f(a))$ and $(c,f(c))$ which must lie above (or at) $f$ for some $b\in [a,c]$

$f(c) \ge f(a) + (c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

If $c \to +\infty$ then

$\displaystyle \lim_{c\to +\infty} f(c) \ge \lim_{c\to +\infty} \left( f(a) + (c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right)$

But since $f$ is bounded, $\lim_{c\to +\infty} f(c)$ should equal some constant $Q$. So we can see that in

$\displaystyle \lim_{c\to +\infty} f(a) + (c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

$(c-a)$ has to cancel somehow. My thought was to first let $c$ go to positive infinity and then $a$ to negative infinity. If then we could somehow lock $f(c)$ between two values which are equal to each other we would have shown $f$ is constant. But I am stuck, any tips?

Comment: Bump! Anyone got any idea how I can show algebraically that f becomes locked in between two values which have to equal each other? Help much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is convex, we have
$$
f(\,\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y\,)\le\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y) \;\;  \forall x, y\in\mathbb{R} ,\;\forall \lambda\in[0,1].
$$
Let $S<\infty$ be the supremum of $f$ (that is, $S=\sup\{f(x),\; x\in\mathbb{R}\}$).

Claim: $f(x)\equiv S$.

Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $z\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z)+\varepsilon>S$. Then

$$
S<\varepsilon +f(z)\le \varepsilon +\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)\le \varepsilon +\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)S
$$
where $y$ is such that $z=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$.

Then
$$
\lambda S <\lambda f(x) +\varepsilon
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is choosen arbitrarly small, we conclude that $S\le f(x)$.

Comment: I haven't come to the level yet (supremum etc). I am pretty sure the argument can be made simpler; any thoughts?

Comment: I understand. Let me think a moment.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not constant, then you can find $ a < b $ such that $ f(a) \neq f(b)$.

If $f(b) > f(a)$, then for any $c > b$, convexity implies that $f(c) \geq f(b) + (c-b)\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} $, and so it is clear that $\underset{{c \to \infty}}{\lim} f(c) = \infty$.

Likewise, if $f(b) < f(a)$, then for any $c < a$, convexity gives $f(c) \geq f(a) + (c-a)\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a-b}$, and so $\underset{{c \to -\infty}}{\lim} f(c) = \infty$.