# $f$ convex, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$, then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a convex function of $\Bbb R$ and suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

How we can prove that $f$ is constant function?

Comment: Are you assuming (1) $\;f\;$ is defined in all of $\;\Bbb R^\;$ , and (2) It is convex in **all** of $\;\Bbb R\;$ ? Otherwise $\;f(x)=\frac1x\;$ is a counterexample in $\;(0,\infty)\;$

Comment: This is a slightly stronger result than http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518091, and Henning Makholm's approach there works here as well.

Answer (score 2):

This answer  is based on the answers here:

[Show bounded and convex function on $\mathbb R$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518091/show-bounded-and-convex-function-on-mathbb-r-is-constant)

So assume $f$ is not constant on $\mathbb R$. Then there are numbers $a<b$ such that $f(a) \ne f(b)$.

Suppose $f(a)<f(b)$. Then take $c>\max(b,0)$. The number $b$ is a convex combination of $a$ and $c$:
$$
b = a \frac{c-b}{c-a} + c \frac{b-a}{c-a} 
$$
Convexity of $f$ implies
$$
f(b) \le \frac{c-b}{c-a} f(a) + \frac{b-a}{c-a} f(c),
$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac{c-a}{b-a}f(b) \le \frac{c-b}{b-a} f(a)  + f(c),
$$
dividing by $c$ yields
$$
\frac{c-a}c \frac{f(b)}{b-a} \le \frac{c-b}c\frac{f(a)}{b-a} + \frac{ f(c)}{c}.
$$
Passing to the limit $c\to\infty$ yields $f(b)\le f(a)$, a contradiction.

Hence it follows $f(b)<f(a)$. Define the function $\tilde f(x):=f(a+b-x)$. Then $\tilde f$ is convex, satisfies $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{\tilde f(x)}x=0$.
Moreover, $\tilde f(a)  =f(b)<f(a)=\tilde f(b)$, which is a contradiction by the first part of the proof above.

It follows that $f$ is constant.

---

Note, how the above proof uses that both limits $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}x$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{f(x)}x$ are zero.

Comment: thanks. In above proof correct last equation as

$\tilde f(a)  =f(b)<f(a)=\tilde f(b)$

Comment: What if $a<b<c<0$? Then if you divide the inequality by $c$, the $\le$ becomes $\ge$.

Comment: We can choose $c>0$ as we are interested in $c\to\infty$.