# Need help with a twice differentiable and bounded function.

Tags: derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ a bounded and twice diffentiable function so that $\begin{equation} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f"(x) \geq 0 \end{equation}. $

My point is to prove that $f$ is constant.

So if I can prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f'(x) = 0$ then my job is done.

So far, I only know that $f'$ is increasing but I don't know how I can use that to end the proof.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for including your progress on the question; that always helps.  Can a function with an increasing derivative be bounded?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang $(f')' = f''$.

Comment: @amsmath You are correct, of course!  I was reacting to an earlier version of the problem that had $f'' \leq 0$ rather than $f'' \geq 0$ as it now shows. I deleted the obsolete comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show bounded and convex function on $\mathbb R$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518091/show-bounded-and-convex-function-on-mathbb-r-is-constant)

Comment: Hint:  Pick two points $a < b$ and suppose $f(a) < f(b)$.  Since $f'' \geq 0$, prove that all $x \geq b$ lie above the line through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

Comment: "Twice" is in the wrong place in the title.

Comment: Just corrected the title thanks!

Comment: I'll try what @Dzooks suggested now !

Comment: I  can reach the point where $f(c) \geq f'(a)(c-a)+f(a)$ with $c \geq b$ but what can I do with $f'(a)$. I feel like I can somehow use the mean-value theorem but I'm lost. Can  you help me with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, if anything's wrong just hit me up.

Let $a < b $ so that $f(a) < f(b)$.

By the mean-value theoreme, $c \in ]a,b[ $ exists  so that $f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<0$.

Let $x \geq b$.

Since $f$ is convex, we have $f(x) \geq f'(b)(x-b)+ f(b).$

But $f'$ is increasing and $b \geq c$ thus $f'(b) \geq f'(c)$.

Finally, $f(x) \geq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-b)+f(b).$

So $\forall x \geq b, f(x) \geq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-b)+f(b).$

As $x \to +\infty$, we can see that $f$ is not bounded hence the contradiction.

As a conclusion, $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an $a\in\mathbb R$ with $f'(a)>0$, then for all $x>a$ we have $f(x)\geq f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)$. [Proof: By the mean value theorem, we have $f(x)= f(a)+(x-a)f'(y)$ for some $y$ between $a$ and $x$. And $f'(y)\geq f'(a)$ because, as you noticed, $f'$ is increasing.] This contradicts the assumption that $f$ is bounded; specifically, $f(x)$ won't be bounded above as $x\to+\infty$.

If there is an $a$ with $f'(a)<0$, then a similar argument shows that $f(x)$ cannot be bounded above as $x\to-\infty$.

So $f'(a)=0$ for all $a$, as required.