# Sufficient condition for convexity involving an average of slopes

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convexity-inequality

Suppose $h(x)\ge0$ is increasing and concave for all $x\ge0$. For $\Delta>0$, let
$$
f(x)=\frac{h(x+\Delta)-h(x)}{\Delta}.
$$
I feel that $f$ is a convex function, i.e.
$$
f(tx+(1-t)y)\le t f(x)+(1-t)f(y), 0<t<1.
$$
But, I don't have any good progress on proving it. Is it obvious true? Or, is there any counterexample? Any reference, help or adivce would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean for all $x \in \Bbb R$? Then your conclusion is “trivially” true because the only concave functions  $h: \Bbb R \to (0, \infty)$ are the *constant* functions.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. $h:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Could you please give me more hints or advices on proving this? Thank you.

Comment: @Tony Whether you include $\,0\,$ or not in the codomain makes no difference. The only concave functions on $\mathbb R$ bounded below are the constant functions. See [Show bounded and convex function on $\mathbb R$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518091/show-bounded-and-convex-function-on-mathbb-r-is-constant).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, $\sqrt(x) $ is nonnegative, increasing and concave on $x\ge0$. What if i change the domain?

Comment: @Tony Please make up your mind on what the question is that you mean to ask, then [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4445876/edit) it into the main post, not as a comment. The answer would likely be negative i.e. a counterexample, but no one can guess your next "*what if*" in advance.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try a small $\,\Delta\,$ with $\,h(x) = \sin x\,$ for $\,x \in [0, \pi/2]\,$ and $\,h(x)=1\,$ for $\,x \gt \pi/2\,$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I learned a lot.